# jQuery find element in variable or object without id then hide

Tags: jquery, html, string, element

How to find tr in variable data **without** any child td's with an id then hide tr?

I have:

```
var data = '<table class="hours">
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <td id="1">text</td>
                 <td>text</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td>text</td>
               </tr>
             </tbody>
            </table>';
```

In above example, the second tr should be hidden, the first should not.

I tried this but it's not working:

```
$jq(data).find(".hours tr:not([id])").hide();
```

Can anyone suggest the way to correctly achieve this?

**Update/My solution**:

`$jq('tr').not(':has([id])').hide();`

Comment: Thanks all for help. After further research I came up with this solution which solves my problem:


    `$jq('tr').not(':has([id])').hide();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one thing in your code. You are already at the root element therefore you will not be able to find that using selector: `.hours`. You can do it like below:

```js
var data = `<table class="hours">
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <td id="1">text1</td>
                 <td>text2</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td>text3</td>
               </tr>
             </tbody>
            </table>`;

var $result = $(data).find('tr:not(:has([id]))').hide();

console.log( $result.closest('table')[0].outerHTML );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

`$jq('tr').not(':has([id])').hide();`

.not - https://api.jquery.com/not/

:has - https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

see original question for context